# Question about finding the volume of a Sphere to a certain point

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

[image]

I've done a few things but I cant seem to figure out how to solve this. Any help please?

Comment: hint: what's the area of the slice of constant height? hint: it's a circle, and you can use the pythagorean theorem to get its size. Can you integrate these?

Comment: You should probably put here what you've tried, so we can help you better (:

Answer (score 2):

Area=$pi(r)^2$

Area=$pi(2Ry-y^2)$

integral of Area from $y=0$ to $y=R/3$ =Volume.

$R=sqrt((R-y)^2+r^2)$

$R^2=(R-y)^2+r^2$

$R^2=R^2-2Ry+y^2+r^2$

$2Ry-y^2+r^2$

$r=sqrt(2Ry-y^2)$

integral of $pi(2Ry-y^2)dy$ from $0$ to $R/3 = pi(Ry)^2-y^3/3$ from $0$ to $R/3$

after plugging in, your answer should be $pi((R(R/3))^2-(R/3)^3/3)$. I hope this was helpful!!